# How unique id in sugar crm modules such as in Emails module are generated?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Need to know that how "`create_guid`" function work and how it generate `IDs` for different modules e.g. `Emails` module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may just call it like

```
$next_meeting->id = create_guid();
```

for example in logic hook. The function itself placed in /include/utils.php file .

Of course, you have to save newly generated bean with

```
$next_meeting->save();
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to call it in following manner:

```
$Module_Bean->new_with_id = true; 
$Module_Bean->id = create_guid();
```

Note that if you assigned your own ID using create_guid function then "new_with_id" need to be set as well. You can find function at  this path: *include\utils.php*

Following is the function body:

```
function create_guid()
{
    $microTime = microtime();
    list($a_dec, $a_sec) = explode(' ', $microTime);

    $dec_hex = dechex($a_dec * 1000000);
    $sec_hex = dechex($a_sec);

    ensure_length($dec_hex, 5);
    ensure_length($sec_hex, 6);

    $guid = '';
    $guid .= $dec_hex;
    $guid .= create_guid_section(3);
    $guid .= '-';
    $guid .= create_guid_section(4);
    $guid .= '-';
    $guid .= create_guid_section(4);
    $guid .= '-';
    $guid .= create_guid_section(4);
    $guid .= '-';
    $guid .= $sec_hex;
    $guid .= create_guid_section(6);

    return $guid;
}
```